# How feasible is it to reuse the bricks when rebuilding a wall?

Tags: walls, brick

I knocked down a wall (drove into it). I have had two builders along to quote for repairing this wall.

One builder says that he can reuse the bricks to rebuild the wall. The other says that there is no way he could reuse the bricks and will need to buy a new set of bricks.

I would prefer to reuse the bricks if possible because it is a lot cheaper and by reusing the bricks means they will blend in with the rest of the wall better. But obviously if reusing the bricks means it will be a shoddy job, it would be better to go with new.

So, which is it? How good a wall can you make with second hand bricks?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When someone says something isn't feasible, they usually mean "I don't have the skills", or "I can't do this cost effectively", or simply "the job looks unpleasant. Of course bricks can be reused if they're not disintegrating. It's simply a matter of whether you really want to pay for that outcome.

That said, it's probably *not* cheaper to reuse the bricks. Bricks are cheap. Time spent disassembling and cleaning bricks isn't (if you're paying someone else to do it). The reason you'd reuse them isn't cost, but outcome. New bricks obviously don't look the same as old ones.

The answer to your question, at its essence, is yes. You can reuse bricks. Humans have done it for centuries.

P.S. I love that you posted the damage to the wall *and* the car.

Comment: Great point about the false economy of reusing the old bricks. One question, though....is it possible to just reattach that whole, intact, "chunk" of wall without freeing and cleaning its individual bricks one-by-one? If so I could imagine that might actually be cheaper.

Comment: Yep. The mason might need to support it temporarily with spacers, since the combined weight of the thing might want to squish the mortar out of the joint. But yep.

Comment: Any loose bricks will need to be removed, cleaned up, and re-mortared, though. That's where the time adds up.

Comment: Thanks. The reusing bricks guy quoted a much lower price, hence the cheaper bit. Perhaps he doesn't value his time as much as the other guy. I estimate the intact chunk to weight about 200kgs, not sure how he would be able to prop it up without at least breaking it up a bit.

Comment: It doesn't weigh that much. Maybe 50kg. Probably less.

Comment: The car already had that damage before I reversed into the wall. I'm quite prolific at bumping into things! This time the car only picked up a very small scratch.

Comment: On second look there are more bricks in that thing than I initially estimated. Probably not more than 100kg, though.

Comment: There are about 50 bricks in there. I think I read somewhere each brick is about 3.5kgs. I wasn't able to budge it at all when I tried, so it is pretty heavy!

Comment: [Looks like about 2kg per](http://www.beldenbrick.com/brick-dimensions-guide.asp). I was under.

Comment: @MongusPong - in a comment above you mentioned "perhaps he (the mason who offered to reuse the bricks) doesn't value his time as much as the other guy." I wouldn't jump to conclusions. He may be ignorant as to the time and effort required to clean and re-use old bricks. Besides asking for our opinions, I would also get references on the contractors so you can get some idea on whether or not to believe their estimates.